# The p-adic value of Dirichlet L-function at 1

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, l-functions, dirichlet-character

I'm reading the book An introduction to p-adic L-functions recently. The book can be found in https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/cwilliams/lecturenotes/lecture_notes_part_i.pdf.
In 4.4, the author claimed that the value of the p-adic L-funtion $L_p(\theta,s)$ at $s=1$ is as following:
\begin{equation}
L_p(\theta,1)=-(1-\theta(p)p^{-1})\frac{1}{G(\theta^{-1})}\sum_{a\in(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^{\times}}\theta^{-1}(a)log_p(1-\zeta^a)
\end{equation}
I followed the book and get the formula above. However, I have a question about the formula. The convergence radius of $log_p(1+x)$ is |x|<1 in $\mathbb{C}_p$, but the p-adic absolute value of $\zeta$ is 1. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Higher up on page 30 they say that value comes from setting $T = 0$ in $\log((1+T)\zeta^a-1)$, so what did you think that power series in $T$ meant when you saw it in Lemma 4.21?  Also, look up the "Iwasawa logarithm", which is an extension of the $p$-adic log from $1 + \mathfrak m_p$ to all of $\mathbf C_p^\times$.

Comment: Well, I think the logarithm is the p-adic logarithm as usual. Can you recommend some books about Iwasawa logarithm? I have just searched online but there seems not much useful.

Comment: I have got one. Thank you very much.